# ArgumentException when using USB to connect to Android phone with C#

Tags: c#, android, uwp, connection, usb

I want to have an Android app communicate with a UWP C# program via USB. I have my phone showing up in Device Manager as an ADB interface with the winusb.sys driver. To communicate with it, I want to put the phone into Accessory mode, for which I need to send a USB control packet (https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/aoa?hl=en#attempt-to-start-in-accessory-mode). But whenever I try to send it, I get an ArgumentException.

I wrote the following code in C#:

```
//vendor id and product id of phone
uint vid = 0x1004;
uint pid = 0x633E;
string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);

DeviceInformationCollection devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

UsbDevice usbDevice = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id); // get UsbDevice

if (usbDevice != null)
{

    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    IBuffer buf = bytes.AsBuffer();

    UsbSetupPacket initSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket()
    {
        RequestType = new UsbControlRequestType()
        {
            Direction = UsbTransferDirection.In,
            Recipient = UsbControlRecipient.Device,
            ControlTransferType = UsbControlTransferType.Vendor,
        },
        Request = 51,
        Value = 0,
        Index = 0,
        Length = 2
    };

    
    IBuffer result = await usbDevice.SendControlInTransferAsync(initSetupPacket, buf);
}
```

My problem is that an ArgumentException ('Value does not fall within the expected range.') is thrown when calling usbDevice.SendControlInTransferAsync and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to just set the `UsbSetupPacket.RequestType Property`?